# Pipes vs process substitution

Tags: bash, pipe, process-substitution

While trying the `cat "$@"` trick to read from either standard input *or* given files, it turned out that *pipe and process substitution handle a missing trailing newline differently*:

```
printf %s foo > test.txt

unset REPLY
while read
do
    :
done < <(cat test.txt)
echo "$REPLY" # Prints foo

unset REPLY
cat test.txt | while read
do
    :
done
echo "$REPLY" # Prints nothing!
```

Is this by design? Is this "feature" documented anywhere?

D'oh! @fered had the right idea - It's just another example of how variable values are lost because [piped commands are run in a subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: Only in ATT ksh (ksh88 and ksh93, but not pdksh) and in zsh does the right-hand side of a pipe run in the parent shell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Variables in a pipe never make it out of the pipe alive :)
Process substitution redirects the data to a file descriptor. Behind the scenes, that process is not the same as a `|` pipe.  The following works, because it is all within the same pipe.

```
unset REPLY
cat test.txt | { 
  while read ;do : ;done
  echo "$REPLY" 
} # Prints foo!
```