# Redirecting from right to left

Tags: pipe

From old habits, I'm always redirecting "from left to right", eg.

1. `cat file | bar`
2. `foo | bar`

I've noticed you can redirect "from right to left". However, is it possible to do this for the second form (eg. from one program to another)?

1. `bar < file`
2. `bar ??? foo`

Also, I'm curious if there is any conventions for when to use "from left" Vs. "from right", or if it's just matter of preference or whatever is most short or elegant.

Comment: Related: [Process substitution and pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe) and [Pipes vs process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23271/pipes-vs-process-substitution)

Comment: `bar < file` isn't piping, it's input redirection.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you could use Bash [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) feature to simulate second form:

```
$ echo foobar | grep bar
foobar
$ grep bar <(echo foobar)
foobar
```

Notice that for this to work command in use has to be able to accept file as a parameter - `grep` does it.

Comment: This doesn't work for `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a lines <(echo a)`. Maybe this is exactly your disclaimer about accepting files? Is it possible to pipe from the right for this particular example?

Comment: @forthrin `read` reads from standard input, so it would need to be `read -d '' -r -a lines < <(echo a)`

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thanks for clarifying how this works. I've wondered about this for years :)

Comment: That second example should also be `grep bar < <(echo foobar)` to have `grep` read input from its `stdin`, and not from a named file (even a special one named behind the scenes)

Comment: @ilkkachu: indeed, and it would be even more portable. Answers that steeldriver has linked to under the question talk about that.

Answer (score -1):

In general you can think of commands between the pipe `|` as being run in a subshell.

So

```
foo | bar
```

could be thought of as

```
(foo) | (bar)
```

So this may help understand how redirection fits into things.

```
foo < bar | baz
```

would be the equivalent to

```
(foo < bar) | (baz)
```

ie the input to `foo` will be the file `bar`, and the output of that will be the input to `baz`.

Process substitution follows the same redirection rules:

```
foo <(echo bar) | baz
```

is the equivalent of

```
( foo <(echo bar) ) | (baz)
```