# How to pipe output to the left

Tags: pipe

When working with gdb, I often need to redirect the output of a command to the process in gdb. However, I can't do `./script | run` in gdb so I often have to pipe the output to a file or named pipe and pipe that file/pipe with `run < file`.

Is there a way to "left-pipe" the output?

Comment: is this strictly related to GDB? if so, I would advise adding the related tags and maybe edit your question so it relate mainly to GDB...(so other answering won't be confuse)

Comment: while I don't know what is the `gdb` (GNU Debugger? still not familiar with it), but maybe this should work for you, `run <(./script)`? using process substitution

Comment: similar to @αғsнιη answer, you could try this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/4521023/12349101

Comment: @NordineLotfi This isn't really about gdb. I'm just looking for a way to pipe from right to left instead of the usual `left | right`. Doing `run <(cmd)` doesn't work, and 4521015 is piping a file like `run < file` and not a process stdout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting from right to left](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503990/redirecting-from-right-to-left)